Sitecore Forms 9.2 compatibility with Webforms
I am in process of migrating existing Sitecore 8.2 to 9.2.
The entire application is based on Web Forms and there is no MVC used.
There are a few WFFM forms which I need to migrate/rewrite in a new application.
Content and code migration has been done and now I am focusing on forms migration.
I created a new form using Sitecore Experience Forms and tried to render it by replacing the existing WFFM form on a page. It does not work and throws an exception.
Is it really possible to render Sitecore Experience forms in non-MVC application? And if it is possible then what rendering I should use?

The Web Forms For Marketers module was deprecated with the release of Sitecore XP 9.1 yet.
Both ASP.NET MVC and Web Forms development models can be used in the same solution, but an MVC rendering will not render in an .ASPX layout. Therefore, the long-term solution is to rebuild your layouts as MVC layouts and use MVC renderings. Unfortunately, there is no any automated path for migration to Sitecore Forms from WFFM and you need to develop your new forms in Sitecore Forms at your own pace and place them on pages with the MVC layout.
Of course, the re-development of legacy WFFM-based forms along with transition to MVC from Web Forms is a big task on its own and might be very time-consuming. As an interim solution it would be possible to iframe your Sitecore Form in your existing .ASPX layout, here are the key steps to get you there:

Create your new Sitecore Form;
Create an empty MVC canvas with a placeholder where you will render your Sitecore Form (MVCLayout.cshtml);
Create your MVC Form rendering;
Create a new page with the MVC layout and place the MVC Form rendering onto it; this page will be the source to your iframe;
Now all is ready and you can create an iframe in your .ASPX layout and link it to the MVC page rendering the Sitecore Form.

Hope this helps.
See also great blogs supporting your transition to Sitecore Forms and MVC:
https://joaoneto.blog/is-it-time-to-migrate-my-wffm-forms-to-sitecore-forms/
https://ericastockwellalpert.wordpress.com/2022/11/18/how-to-render-a-sitecore-mvc-form-in-an-aspx-page/
